# Laravel 5.4 - Array returning NULL instead of a numeric value

Tags: arrays, laravel, null

Here's a problem that is bothering me for a while.

I have a service provider to pass data to all views, everytime the sidebar is rendered. like this:

```
`      
   public function boot()
   {

   $userrole = array (DB::table('users')->where('id','=', Auth::id())->value('role'));
   $menucase1 = [3,4,9,10];         
   $menucase2 = [1,2,3,10]; 
   $menucase3 = [1,3,4,9,10];
   $menucase4 = [4,9];

   $commondata = compact('userrole','menucase1','menucase2','menucase3','menucase4');

    view()->share('commondata', $commondata);
    View::composer('sidebar', function ($view) {
        $userrole = array (DB::table('users')->where('id','=', Auth::id())->value('role'));
        $menucase1 = [3,4,9,10];
        $menucase2 = [1,2,3,10];
        $menucase3 = [1,3,4,9,10]; 
        $menucase4 = [4,9];
        $commondata = compact('userrole','menucase1','menucase2','menucase3','menucase4');
    $view->with('commondata', $commondata);
    });

}`
```

Doing a `{{ dd($commondata) }}` returns the correct values for the menucase arrays, but `NULL` for the `$userrole`

If i declare the same `$userrole` variable in a controller and call the variable in the view, the received data is correct.

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's cause session starts after controller create.

Comment: so, just check Auth::id - it's will be null.

Comment: thanks, i've just printed the userid, like this `{{ Auth::id() }}`, and it returned a value.

Comment: @KollleY - How do i check if my session is starting after the controller start... i'm a newbie

Comment: dd(Auth::id());

Comment: What is 'role' here `->value('role')`? is it in the user table or a separate table with a relationship from user?

Comment: @EddyTheDove the role is in the users table. just the integer. there is another table called roles, with an ID, role name and description.

Comment: which array do you want? role from users table or roles from the roles tables that belong to user? Does it mean a user has many roles ?

Comment: @EddyTheDove - In the future, an user might have multiple roles. for now, only one. I don't know if the query is ok, but what i want is to get the role in the users table. the thinig is, if i declare a variable in a controller i can pass the role correctly, but when passing that same variable to an array, i get null, the query is exactly the same. someone told that maybe the session is starting after the controller, i think it might, but i have no idea of what to do...

Comment: If the user has only one role, then why do you want an array? ccheck my answer below and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand what are you actually trying to do.

If you want get user role as array, you can using `pluck` method:

```
$userRole = User::where('id', Auth::id())->pluck('role')->toArray();
```

But for current user you can just get the role

```
$userRole = [Auth::user()->role];
```

UPD: you also can do it in view without any sharing

```
{{ Auth::user()->role }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The main objective is to filter the content of the sidebar links depending on the role of the users. I know that there are complete packages to achieve that, i'e tried them, but i am a newbie and never got to make any of the other solutions work.... So i've tried to pass a set of data that i know it will be needed to all the pages, userrole and the menu conditions (to test with ifs).  I have tried your first solution `$userRole = User::where('id', Auth::id())->pluck('role')->toArray();
` and it returned na empty array for the userrole index

Comment: @MarcoAssunção This is a great package for roles/permissions control. Check it, maybe you'll find it useful. https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: I have tested it, but the idea i got is that i was going to need to change a lot of things in my project. for now i am just trying a more simple solution. I am a newbie... small steps :)

Comment: if in my view i do this `{{ Auth::user()->role }}`, it shows the user role. But if i change this `$userrole = array (DB::table('users')->where('id','=', Auth::id())->value('role'));` for this `{{ Auth::user()->role }}` in the service provider i get the error `Trying to get property of non-object`. So as someone said before, i might be starting the controller before the session start. I have no idea of what to do next...

Answer (score 0):

If your user has many roles from a different table, and you have the relationship defined, you could do

```
$userrole = Auth::user()->roles->pluck('name');

//will return all the roles names in an array
//Replace name by the actual column you want from 'roles' table.
```